Entity Graph not generating left join
Im looking to get the Entity Graph working so I can have left join on the employee entity when finding by id to also retrive the job positions at the same time.
Currently I can see that there are 2 select queries running & the only way for me to fix it is to use FetchType.EAGER on the jobPositions field although this generates the n+1 issue for me.
Therefore I'd like to utilise the EntityGraph although I can get it to work without the FetchType.EAGER. Anyone able to help on this one?
import com.example.personmanagement.model.person.Person;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.EntityGraph;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Person> {
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"jobPositions"},type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    Optional<Person> findById(Long id);
}

import com.example.personmanagement.model.person.Person;
import com.example.personmanagement.model.position.JobPosition;
import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.DiscriminatorValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.NamedAttributeNode;
import jakarta.persistence.NamedEntityGraph;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

import java.util.Set;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("EMPLOYEE")
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "jobPositions",
        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("jobPositions")
)
public class Employee extends Person {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee")
    private Set<JobPosition> jobPositions;
}

Hibernate: 
    select
        p1_0.id,
        p1_0.type,
        p1_0.email_address,
        p1_0.height,
        p1_0.name,
        p1_0.pesel,
        p1_0.surname,
        p1_0.type,
        p1_0.version,
        p1_0.weight,
        p1_0.pension_amount,
        p1_0.worked_years,
        p1_0.course_name,
        p1_0.name_of_university,
        p1_0.scholarship,
        p1_0.year_of_studies 
    from
        person p1_0 
    where
        p1_0.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        j1_0.employee_id,
        j1_0.id,
        j1_0.end_date,
        j1_0.position_name,
        j1_0.salary,
        j1_0.start_date 
    from
        job_position j1_0 
    where
        j1_0.employee_id=?
Hibernate: 
    update
        person 
    set
        email_address=?,
        height=?,
        name=?,
        pesel=?,
        surname=?,
        version=?,
        weight=? 
    where
        id=? 
        and version=?

Ive tried FetchType.EAGER although this is generating the n+1 for me when used on the jobPostions field.
I need to setup the Entity Graph for it to left join the values from the employee with the use of 1 select rather than 2.
